# iptables limit number of outgoing connections on a port

Tags: iptables

I'm currently using the following to limit the number of incoming connections on port 9001 to 900.

```
iptables -t filter -I INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 9001 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 900 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

However, what I really want to do is limit the total number of connections, incoming or outgoing, on port 9001 to 1800. Can I modify this rule or append a new one to get the desired result?

I posted this question on stackoverflow first and have gotten downvoted with no explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You could try --connlimit with the --connlimit-mask option to set a mask of 0.

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport XXY -m connlimit --connlimit-above 5 --connlimit-mask 0 -j REJECT`

Where XXY is the port that you want to rate-limit connections to.

already answered here : https://serverfault.com/questions/371763/limit-maximum-incoming-connections-to-a-port-using-iptables

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I think you misread my question. Please read the title again.

Comment: I'm looking to limit outgoing connections, not incoming connections.